# ABAP IXML removes multiple blanks

Tags: xml, abap

When creating a ixml element and setting the value as text type cstring containing `12345     67890` the spaces will be rendered as a single space `12345 67890`. How can I stop ABAP from combining my spaces?

```
DATA(li_doc) = cl_ixml=>create( )->create_document( ).

" INITIALIZE XML

DATA(li_new_node) = li_doc->create_element_ns( name = |test| prefix = |foo| ).
li_new_node->append_child( li_doc->create_text( |12345    67890| ) ).
li_doc->append_child( li_new_node ).

" RENDER XML

DATA: l_xml_string TYPE string.

DATA(li_ixml) = cl_ixml=>create( ).
DATA(li_streamfactory) = li_ixml->create_stream_factory( ).
DATA(li_ostream) = li_streamfactory->create_ostream_cstring( l_xml_string ).

DATA(li_renderer) = li_ixml->create_renderer( ostream = li_ostream document = li_doc ).
li_renderer->set_normalizing( abap_false ).
li_renderer->render( ).

WRITE l_xml_string.
```

Comment: `How can I stop` it depends on how you create your XML. Show us the code

Comment: Okay I changed nothing, but it works now. Kinda (un)fortunate.

Comment: `cstring( |12345    67890| )` i believe you use var here, not literal, and it seems this var was of char type, not string. That's why it works now

Answer (score 1):

As you said, your code doesn't have any issue, blanks are not removed, as expected. Note that when you [think better of your question, you may delete it - nobody minds](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

But as I see you didn't, maybe a future visitor will have an issue of "removed blanks" in iXML, so I explain one case where it may happen.

Blanks may be removed when you **parse** a XML string, not when you render. Example:

```
DATA: l_xml_string TYPE string.

DATA(li_ixml) = cl_ixml=>create( ).
DATA(li_doc) = li_ixml->create_document( ).
DATA(li_streamfactory) = li_ixml->create_stream_factory( ).

" INITIALIZE XML

l_xml_string = '<?xml version="1.0"?><foo:test>    12345    67890    </foo:test>'.

" PARSE XML

DATA(li_Istream) = li_streamfactory->create_istream_cstring( l_xml_string ).
DATA(li_parser) = li_ixml->create_parser( document = li_doc istream = li_istream stream_factory = li_streamfactory ).
li_parser->parse( ).

l_xml_string = li_doc->get_root_element( )->get_value( ).

WRITE : '=>' NO-GAP, l_xml_string NO-GAP, '<='.
```

the result has the leading and trailing blanks removed:

```
=>12345    67890<=
```

If you add this line before `li_parser->parse( )`:

```
li_parser->add_preserve_space_element( ).
```

the result has the leading and trailing blanks unchanged:

```
=>    12345    67890    <=
```